# Como adicionar custom fields na busca do backend do WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Na página de um tipo personalizado, **na administração**, ele lista o título do projeto e a data, e assim a busca funciona apenas nesses dois campos.

Como fazer para que no momento da busca ele procure também nos custom fields?
Quais arquivos preciso modificar?
Que função devo usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução está nesta resposta do WordPress Developers:
[*How to filter post listing (in WP dashboard posts listing) using a custom field (search functionality)?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16641/12615)

[image]

Primeiro, é preciso adicionar o dropdown e o input de texto, ajustando o Post Type na comparação com `$typenow`:

```
/**
 * Adicionar filtro de Custom Fields na tela /wp-admin/edit.php
 */
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );

function ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts()
{
    global $wpdb, $typenow;
    if( $typenow !== 'post' ) // AJUSTE SEU POST TYPE
        return;

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_key FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' ORDER BY 1';
    $fields = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_N );
    ?>
    <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By Custom Fields', 'baapf'); ?></option>
        <?php
        $current = isset( $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] ) ? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] : '';
        $current_v = isset( $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] ) ? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] : '';
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) 
        {
            # Hidden fields
            if ( substr( $field[0], 0, 1 ) != "_" )
            {
                printf(
                    '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                    $field[0],
                    $field[0] == $current ? ' selected="selected"' : '',
                    $field[0]
                );
            }
        }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <?php _e('Value:', 'baapf'); ?>
    <input type="TEXT" name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE" value="<?php echo $current_v; ?>" />
    <?php
}
```

Depois, adicionar o filtro quando a pesquisa acontecer dentro da página `/wp-admin/edit.php` e o `$_GET` correto estiver setado:

```
/**
 * Fazer a filtragem conforme o $_GET
 */
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'ba_admin_posts_filter' );

function ba_admin_posts_filter( $query )
{
    global $pagenow;
    $get_url = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] != '';
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $get_url ) 
    {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'];
        if (isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '')
            $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
}
```

Note que a busca é literal pelo "Value" e que os *fields* com *arrays* serializadas não são considerados.

---

Testei [esta outra solução](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143595/12615) para fazer a filtragem e parece que funciona com fields serializados (testes mais profundos são necessários):

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse143477_parse_clauses', 10, 2 );

function wpse143477_parse_clauses($clauses, $query) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;
    $get_url = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] != '';
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $get_url ) 
    {
        $keyword = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
        $keyword = '%' . like_escape( $keyword ) . '%';
        $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
            WHERE meta_key = '%s' AND meta_value LIKE '%s'
        ", $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'], $keyword ) );
        if( !empty( $post_ids )) {
            $clauses['where'] .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ', ', $post_ids ) . ')';
        }
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```

---

<sup>PS: Esse tipo de código pode ir `functions.php`, mas é mais adequado [como um **plugin**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).</sup>

Comment: Então, acontece que o que eu quero de verdade mesmo, é que não seja necessário incluir o dropdown. Quero buscar naquele campo de texto padrão e que ele traga as correspondências de todos os campos no banco. Tem como?

Comment: @IgorBarreto, a [edição que você sugeriu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17538) é mais adequada como um comentário. Na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) tem mais detalhes.

Comment: Bom, adaptei a resposta levando em conta sua observação.